# Newline character sequence in CSS 'content' property?

Tags: css

Is it possible to use **newline** character in CSS `content` property to force a line break? Something like:

```
figcaption:before
{
    content: 'Figure \n' + attr(title);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4609491/582278

Comment: @Blowski, yeah, but it doesn't work in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/q4WC4/)

Comment: @SaeedNeamati does in mine. What browser are you looking in?

Comment: Now it works. The last [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/q4WC4/3/)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of [the question indicated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7363766/17300). That one asks how to create a break _before_ starting the generated content, which can be done using `display`, `clear` etc. _This_ question asks how to put newlines/line-breaks _**within**_ the generated content, which is what I want, and that _can't_ be accomplished the same way.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

The [content](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content) property accepts a [string](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#strings) and:

> A string cannot directly contain a newline. To include a newline in a
> string, use an escape representing the line feed character in
> ISO-10646 (U+000A), such as "\A" or "\00000a". This character
> represents the generic notion of "newline" in CSS.

The tricky bit is to remember that HTML collapses white-space by default.

```css
figure {
    /* Avoid whitespace collapse to illustrate what works and what doesn't */
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}

#first figcaption:before
{
    /* \n is not a valid entity in this context */
    content: 'Figure \n Chemistry';
    display: block;  
}

#second figcaption:before
{
    content: 'Figure \A Chemistry';
    display: block;  
}
```

```html
<figure id='first'>
    <figcaption>Experiments</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure id='second'>
    <figcaption>Experiments</figcaption>
</figure>
```

You can check [Using character escapes in markup and CSS](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes) for reference about the escape syntax, which essentially is:

- `\20AC` must be followed by a space if the next character is one of a-f, A-F, 0-9
- `\0020AC` must be 6 digits long, no space needed (but can be included)

NOTE: use `\00000a` rather than just `\A` when escaping an arbitrary string, because if the newline is followed by a number or any character from `[a-f]` range, this may give an [undesired result](http://jsfiddle.net/ob5490rL/).

Comment: Note that newline characters inserted this way are treated like any other newlines in an HTML document: they'll be rendered as a regular space character by browsers by default, and only as regular newlines in preformatted content.

Comment: It doesn't work. [jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/q4WC4/).

Comment: @SaeedNeamati - It does: http://jsfiddle.net/q4WC4/1/

Comment: Then you should also include `white-space` property, yeah? Am I right?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati - The key is on @BoltClock's comment. Playing with `white-space` is just a simple way to make line feeds visible.

Comment: This doesn't work if `content: attr(some-attr)` if e.g. `some-attr="foo \A bar"`. Any ideas about what to do in this case?

Comment: @Griffin - You can use the HTML code for a new line in that case `&#10;`, but you also still need `white-space: pre-wrap` or something similar on the element.

Answer (score 181):

```css
figcaption:before
{
    content: 'Figure \a' attr(title);
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Note that in the `content` attribute value, concatenation is expressed just by whitespace, not by a “+” sign. The escape notation `\a` in a CSS string literal indicates a linebreak character.

Comment: Still not working. Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/q4WC4/2/)

Comment: The `white-space: pre` was missing.
See http://jsfiddle.net/FP5gX/
where I added `' '` as you probably want that space.

Comment: @Jan should we use `::before` or `:before`?

Comment: @Ormoz it definitely needs to be `:before`. You were probably confused by Dave Jarvis' edit of the accepted answer, which used bad syntax and didn't work anyway. I reverted that edit.

Comment: I found "white-space: pre-wrap;" to work even better.

Comment: For longer content which may overflow the container, I suggest you replace `white-space: pre;` with `white-space: pre-line;`

Comment: I want to point out that you should use the double colon notation that was introduced with CSS3: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before since this is a pseudo element and not a pseudo selector.

Comment: But how do you specify a newline character in the attribute that is used by the content in css? I believe that was also part of the main question? \A or \n does not work then, they are just displayed literally as text.