# Add line break to ::after or ::before pseudo-element content

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I do not have access to the HTML or PHP for a page and can only edit via CSS. I've been doing modifications on a site and adding text via the `::after` or `::before` pseudo-elements and have found that escape Unicode should be used for things such as a space before or after the added content.

How do I add multiple lines in the `content` property?

In example the HTML break line element is *only to visualize* what I would like to achieve:

```css
#headerAgentInfoDetailsPhone::after {
  content: 'Office: XXXXX <br /> Mobile: YYYYY ';
}
```

Comment: CSS is not for adding or editing content, it is for controlling how content displays

Comment: @SamithaHewawasam While I agree with your statement, it looks like the poster has found themselves in a situation where they cannot edit the HTML. For small, simple content additions, I can see why this would be useful/necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Newline character sequence in CSS 'content' property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062988/newline-character-sequence-in-css-content-property)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert a line break before an element using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363766/how-to-insert-a-line-break-before-an-element-using-css)

Comment: I would also argue that line breaks are far more format-related than content related. The only way you "see" a line break is by observing a format change in the content.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work if content is filled from an attr (`content:attr('data-message')`)

Answer (score 308, accepted):

The [`content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content) property states:

> Authors may include newlines in the generated content by writing the "\A" escape sequence in one of the strings after the 'content' property. This inserted line break is **still subject to the 'white-space' property.** See "Strings" and "Characters and case" for more information on the "\A" escape sequence.

So you can use:

```css
#headerAgentInfoDetailsPhone:after {
  content:"Office: XXXXX \A Mobile: YYYYY ";
  white-space: pre; /* or pre-wrap */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XkNxs/

When escaping arbitrary strings, however, it's advisable to use `\00000a` instead of `\A`, because any number or `[a-f]` character followed by the new line may give [unpredictable results](http://jsfiddle.net/ob5490rL/):

```js
function addTextToStyle(id, text) {
  return `#${id}::after { content: "${text.replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/\n/g, '\\00000a')} }"`;
}
```

Comment: For a moment I thought "why `\A` and not `\n`" - then I remembered newline is `0x0A` :)

Comment: I tried this in with print media query, it doesn't work. is it a bug or it is the default behaviour? Without print media, it works.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `pre-wrap`! I was having problems with `#headerAgentInfoDetailsPhone` **not wrapping any more in Blink engine web browsers like Chrome.** Firefox is not susceptible to the `white-space: pre;` property propagating back up to the element.

Comment: Babel is giving me `The only valid numeric escape in strict mode is '\0'`

Answer (score 38):

Nice article explaining the basics (does not cover line breaks, however).

[A Whole Bunch of Amazing Stuff Pseudo Elements Can Do](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/)

If you need to have two inline elements where one breaks into the next line within another element, you can accomplish this by adding a pseudo-element :after with content:'\A' and white-space: pre

HTML

```html
<h3>
    <span class="label">This is the main label</span>
    <span class="secondary-label">secondary label</span>
</h3>
```

CSS

```css
.label:after {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I had to have new lines in a tooltip. I had to add this CSS on my :after :

```
.tooltip:after {
  width: 500px;
  white-space: pre;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

The word-wrap seems necessary.

In addition, the \A didn't work in the middle of the text to display, to force a new line.

```
 &#13;&#10;
```

worked. I was then able to get such a tooltip :

[image]

Comment: This is the only one that seems to work when using `content: attr(data-tooltip);` and `<span data-tooltip="First line&#13;&#10;Second line">`

Comment: Same this worked for me too; However I didn't seem to need `word-wrap`. I want to recommend `white-space: pre-line` as this trims off leading and trailing whitespace

Answer (score 11):

You may try this

```css
#headerAgentInfoDetailsPhone
{
    white-space:pre
}
#headerAgentInfoDetailsPhone:after {
    content:"Office: XXXXX \A Mobile: YYYYY ";
}
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YcWjt/)

Answer (score 10):

For people who will going to look for 'How to change dynamically content on pseudo element adding new line sign" here's answer

Html chars like `&#13;&#10;` will not work appending them to html using JavaScript because those characters are changed on document render

Instead you need to find unicode representation of this characters which are U+000D and U+000A so we can do something like

```js
var el = document.querySelector('div');
var string = el.getAttribute('text').replace(/, /, '\u000D\u000A');
el.setAttribute('text', string);
```

```css
div:before{
   content: attr(text);
   white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div text='I want to break it in javascript, after comma sign'></div>
```

Hope this save someones time, good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

**Add line break to `::after` or `::before` pseudo-element content**

```
.yourclass:before {
    content: 'text here first \A  text here second';
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this question here that seems to ask the same thing: [Newline character sequence in CSS 'content' property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062988/newline-character-sequence-in-css-content-property)

Looks like you can use `\A` or `\00000a` to achieve a `newline`

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>Break sentence after the comma,<span class="mbr"> </span>in case of mobile version.</p>
<p>Break sentence after the comma,<span class="dbr"> </span>in case of desktop version.</p>
```

The *.mbr* and *.dbr* classes can simulate line-break behavior using CSS *display:table*. Useful if you want to replace real <br />.

Check out this demo Codepen: https://codepen.io/Marko36/pen/RBweYY,
and this post on responsive site use: [Responsive line-breaks: simulate <br /> at given breakpoints](https://sparkx.online/replace-line-break-element-with-responsive-css/).

Comment: Asked for a CSS not HTML solution.

Comment: But if someone else was searching for "Add line break to ::after or ::before pseudo-element content" and landed here, but actually could edit his HTML, they might this helpful, right?