# Prevent newline break with span and p tag

Tags: html, css

I have some CSS which inserts a dash, unicode U+2014 —,  to give a nice formatting on [my site](http://biochemistri.es) ahead of the stated source. Annoyingly it is breaking a new line after this (I've tried changing from span to div but no use).

[image: Screenshot inspecting the element in Chrome]

The document tree looks like:

```
<span class="source">...</span>
<p>Source author, text goes here etc. etc.</p>
```

The computed style for the `span` line includes `display:inline`, whereas the computed style for `p` has `display:block`, which I'm guessing may be causing the new line?

I'm reading through the relevant CSS and can't see any reason why it should start a new line, I don't have [\A in the content as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047694/add-line-break-to-before-or-after-pseudo-element-content) ...

Can any CSS whiz point me to what I'm missing? Alternative implementation of the `::before` pseudo-element required perhaps?

The CSS involved here is

```
div.source:before{content:"\2014";margin-left:0.9em;margin-right:0.9em; white-space:nowrap;}#content
```

(I inserted white-space:nowrap a while ago trying to fix this but it didn't do anything to the new line)

Comment: Did you try `p{display: inline;}`? Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/TUyVC/) what you want?

Comment: This is because `<p>` is by default a block-level element, meaning that it will take up 100% width of its parent, therefore forcing itself on a new line. Perhaps @Harry's suggestion would work.

Comment: Cringed when I read this because it's basically the solution and I guess I'm an idiot but then I tried it and there are multiple <p> tags (i.e. more paragraphs after the source is stated) so I'm just trying to figure out if I need nth-of-type / first-child to make just the first one display:inline, this feels like over-complicating though ...

Comment: It messes up the p margins for some reason, using nth-of-type got rid of a scrollbar on a blockquote section underneath but going to try Steve's suggestion... 
div.source p:nth-of-type(1){display:inline}

Comment: @lmmx: Like I just mentioned in Steve's answer. His approach is the better one, but just be careful about the list of browsers you want to support. If IE < 9 is in your list then `:before`, `:nth-child` etc will cause trouble.

Comment: But if that's the case, the original solution will not work either. In fact, my solution would degrade gracefully because the paragraph would just work as usual.

Comment: Alternately you could try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/TUyVC/1/) version also. It uses `+` (adjacent sibling selector) and so only applies to the `<p>` tag directly following the `<span>` and IE has better support for this selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the adjacent sibling selector (`+`) like shown below. It is supported in IE >= 7.

**HTML:**

```
<span class="source">&mdash;</span>
<p>Source author, text goes here etc. etc.</p>
<p>Source author, text goes here etc. etc.</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
.source + p{display: inline;} 
/* applies inline style to only the <p> tag directly following a tag with class=source */
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/TUyVC/2/) | [**Browser Support**](http://caniuse.com/css-sel2)

Comment: to have the same effect as div.source p:nth-of-type(1){display:inline} ?

Comment: Yes, it would. Did you check the fiddle?

Comment: Yeah, it's acting a little funny in my actual site I'm just seeing what needs to be modified

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/TUyVC/3/) fiddle. It also puts the dash as required. I am not sure what else is causing trouble in your site. If you can update the fiddle with your exact code that would be helpful in analyzing. (`&mdash;` is the same as `\2014`)

Comment: That is strange mate. Are you able to simulate the issue in a fiddle? Also, I think you would have noted the `div` is missing before `.source` in my answer. That is because the element with `class=source` in our case is a `span`.

Comment: @lmmx: Ah, your `<p>` is inside the `<span>` and is not a sibling. That is the reason.

Comment: Can make it work without the + selector using nth-of-type(1), would be interested to find out what was going wrong though http://jsfiddle.net/qhNzz/

Comment: Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/TUyVC/7/). The problem was that `+` selects a sibling but as mentioned in my previous comment, here the `<p>` is a child and not a sibling of `<span>`. Also, `nth-of-type(1)` is pretty much the same as `p:first-child`. (Note: `first-child` is not supported in IE7)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the `class="source"` directly to the p tag, rather than adding an unnecessary `span`?

The behavior as you see it right now is correct, because `p` elements are by default block level elements. You could give it a style of `display: inline;` but as I mentioned above, it would be better to get rid of the `span` and add the class to the `p` tag.

Comment: I agree with you. While I was just trying to fix the problem, what you have mentioned is the better approach to handling it. However, only thing that needs to be checked is browser support for the `:before` pseudo (IE comes to mind :D)

Comment: I'd like to use that but I'm using Tumblr to manage my posts (although doing my best to hide it) and it doesn't let you change p-level attributes in the theme. The source section looks like this:

{block:Source}<div class="source">{Source}{/block:Source}

Comment: Is there a way to apply class="source" to child elements from the div tag?