# erratic line wrapping with after pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have an html layout which is reflowing in unexpected ways in chrome and safari.
[image: some bad text layout with lines overflowing]

The structure of my document is such that every word in wrapped in a span, and every line is wrapped in a span, and then the document in wrapped in a div.  To separate the lines I use the after pseudo-element [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047694/add-line-break-to-before-or-after-pseudo-element-content).

However, as you can see, the line breaking is erratic.  What is going on here and how to best remedy this situation?  I have found that changing the after pseudo-element from '\A'; to ' \A' the problem seems to go away, but I do not understand why.

```css
.bc {
  border: solid 1px green;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

div > span:after {
  content: '\A';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="bc"><span><span>HELLO, </span><span>how </span><span>is </span><span>Matilda.</span></span><span><span>MATILDA!, </span><span>kinsman </span><span>to </span><span>the </span><span>seahorses, </span><span>and </span><span>friend </span><span>to </span><span>Franklin.</span></span><span><span>EXTRA, </span><span>niece </span><span>to </span><span>Matilda, </span><span>never </span><span>pleasant </span><span>to </span><span>Emanuel.</span></span></div>
```

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516709

Answer (score 1):

if you add `word-wrap` it seems to be working

```css
.bc {
  border: solid 1px green;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
 /*word-wrap: break-word;*/
}

div > span:after {
  content: '\A';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="bc"><span><span>HELLO, </span><span>how </span><span>is </span><span>Matilda.</span></span><span><span>MATILDA!, </span><span>kinsman </span><span>to </span><span>the </span><span>seahorses, </span><span>and </span><span>friend </span><span>to </span><span>Franklin.</span></span><span><span>EXTRA, </span><span>niece </span><span>to </span><span>Matilda, </span><span>never </span><span>pleasant </span><span>to </span><span>Emanuel. </span></span></div>
```

is this what you mean?

Comment: yes, that works.  but as there are no huge words in this example to break, I am puzzled why this solution (and the one in the OP work).

Comment: Yes, but why does that work?   The first long sentence does not require that addition.

Comment: I believe that's how `white-space: pre;` works; try to use `white-space: pre-wrap;` and it will work without trailing space