# Same CSS have different behaviour on two PCs having Chrome

Tags: css

I have added text using the CSS on a page however when checking the page on two different PCs having same version of the Chrome browser there is a mismatch.

CSS

```
div.amenity-item-row.changeTravel div.brand-amenity-value.economy.YV span.amenity-value:lang(en)::after {
    content: "(One date change free)";
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 39px;
}
```

Screen shots
[image: two pcs same chrome version]

Comment: You should use your Chrome Browser Inspector to find out what's different

Comment: My best guess is that there is some cache issue involved

Comment: does it have different OS?

Comment: Try hard reloading your page using Ctrl + F5. If you position your `::after` element using `position: absolute` it is possible, that it will overflow. Try using line break in your `::after`'s content like `white-space: pre; content: "\A(One date change free)";` [Read more.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17047694/12493648)

Comment: @martin, The white space is removed.

Comment: As asked by @imstevanno, are both OS diff? Also what's chrome browser version? And why are you checking with diff currency? tried to set same currency? (Though it should not matter just trying to explore all possibilities)

Comment: Yes the OS are different for both PCs... actually the currency does not affect the CSS so changing the currency did not help.