# How to add line break into tooltip of pandas dataframe styler in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I would like to split "First line Second line" text into two lines in the tooltip while viewing dataframe in Jupyter Notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[*'abcdef'], 'b':[*'abcdef']})
df.style.set_tooltips(df.applymap( lambda x:  "First line Second line"))
```

Current behaviour:

[image]

I have tried adding various types of line breaks into text ( \n,\r\n, ) but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Try HTML line breaks (`<br>`) in the tooltip text.
Here's an example of how u cld do it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [*'abcdef'], 'b': [*'abcdef']})
# Define a function to format tooltip text
def format_tooltip(x):
   return "First line<br>Second line"
# Apply styler with tooltips
styled_df = df.style.set_tooltips(df.applymap(format_tooltip))
# Display styled DataFrame
styled_df
```

The tooltip text will appear with a line brk between "First line" & "Second line" in  Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Thanks, but even with "<br>" I still get one liner with text "First line<br>Second line".

Answer (score 0):

Styler uses css pseudo after selectors to add tooltips.

Try the advice here: [Add line break to ::after or ::before pseudo-element content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047694/add-line-break-to-after-or-before-pseudo-element-content)

Comment: That is correct.  Using white-space: pre and \a as a new line.

Comment: An upvote and accept the answer is generally recommended. Thx