# Are these two CSS new line characters the same? \a, \A

Tags: css

I wanted to confirm if `\a` and `\A` are both the same CSS new line character, and that being capital letter or small letter doesn't matter here?

```
Like for example these are the same:
#content1::after{
    content: "\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
#content1::after{
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Why don’t you just test it yourself

Comment: You might want to check answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062988/newline-character-sequence-in-css-content-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might Yes, these characters represent the generic notion of "newline" in CSS