# why attr() don't work here? if I put "\a" CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, escaping, pseudo-element

1. I have a code in javascript that generates a string
2. and then that string is placed in an attribute in the HTML tag
3. and then I have a `::after` element with `content: attr(data-after);`

and I saw here [Newline character sequence in CSS 'content' property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062988/newline-character-sequence-in-css-content-property)

that  for making `<br>` like behavior,

I need `\a` inside the string

I do it manually without attr() and is working fine

```
content: "hello \a world";
/* output: 
hello
world
*/
```

but if you get the string from the attribute then it become `output: hello world` in one line.

I saw that `\a` is displayed in the attribute, so in the string I putted 2  `\\a` for escaping the `\`

but still not going in new line.

```js
document.querySelector("#container").setAttribute("data-after", "lenght: 86.02325267042627 \\a x: 110 \\a y: 100 \\a angle: 54.46232220802561");
```

```css
#container::after {
  content: attr(data-after);
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Please add a [mre] to your question using the `<>` button.

Comment: @ChrisG added the details

Comment: It actually works if you use `\n` instead :) Looks like `\a` is a workaround for putting it in the CSS and just for that