# Clearing an inline-block element to the next line

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to clear an inline-block element (in this case an `<a>` within a `<p>`) to the next line, without having to set `display:block` and defining a width.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/alecrust/zstKf/

Here's the desired result (using `display:block` and defining a width): http://jsfiddle.net/alecrust/TmwhU/

Comment: why not `<br>` or `</p><p>` ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, the `<a>` needs to remain in the `<p>` and I'd like to achieve this without a `<br>`.

Comment: Yes - but what if you close the `<p>` after the `<a>` and open it again?

Comment: I don't follow, could you provide a Fiddle?

Perhaps I should specify even more: the markup needs to remain as-is.

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle, but that splits it in to two elements which will of course stack correctly. I'm trying to clear an inline-block element to the next line, without affecting the markup.

Comment: Hmmmm I don't think you can :/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid setting an explicit width so you can style the background according to the actual length of the text, you can do the following:

Wrap your link:

```
 <p>To stay up to date <span><a href="#">Follow Us</a></span></p>
```

Note that I have added a `<span>` tag around the link.

Style your wrapper with CSS:

```
 span {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

Setting the width to 100% forces the wrapper to take up the whole line. Keeping the `<a>` tag for the link set to inline-block allows it to have padding and a background applied while not having it expand to fit the container's width of 100%.

Forked JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cm9kZ/

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a kludge, but it will work:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 18px;
    background-color: #8C4AD5;
    text-decoration: none;
    position:relative;
    top:25px;
    left:-30%
}
```

You'll have to fudge the left position, but that basically puts you back into setting a known value, just like the width issue in your `display:block` example. Not really any better, just a different approach.

Comment: I hadn't though of that approach, thanks. As you say though, it's just replacing one fixed-width technique with another.

Comment: Not really I'm afraid. I'd probably change the markup to solve it before I took that approach. Was just curious if this was achievable with CSS using the existing markup.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can get to what I want is using `:before` to insert a new line before the `<a>` ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alecrust/TF2AT/)). This unfortunately doesn't clear it to the next line though.

Comment: That would never work. `a:before` goes inside and at the start of the `a`, not *before* it. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/TF2AT/1/.

Answer (score 1):

*This only works if you want to line break after the last element in the p.*

I've experimented quite a bit and this works for me, in Safari 6:

```
p.linebreak-after-last-element:after {
   content: "";
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
}
```

I have not tested this in other browsers, but it's so simple it should work in all browsers supporting `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

An empty `<div/>` after the inline-block element, clears the inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

With the requirements you have, I don't think it's possible.

I was hoping that [this would help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609279/css-to-line-break-before-after-a-particular-inline-block-item/4609491#4609491), but it doesn't because you don't have an element before your link.

You should just change your HTML, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/zstKf/10/

Comment: Yes, aware a `<br>` does the trick. Was just curious if it could be done without, I was hoping with `:before` on the anchor or something. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You could use the trick from the answer I linked if you wrapped your text in a `span`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/zstKf/11/. It's just not worth it though.

Comment: Agreed. That's another one I hadn't thought of though - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the pseudo class :: after you could add content with a `clear:both`; property to it.

Not tested but should work in theory.