# How do I set dynamic width to a block element?

Tags: html, css

I have 30 elements with class `.lollipop` that has `line-height: 30px; height: 30px;`.

```
<a class="lollipop">Random text</a>
<a class="lollipop">Random text longer</a>
<a class="lollipop">Short</a>
...
```

How do I write the CSS to have dynamic width (their width adapt based on how much text is there inside them, like it usually is) and have only one of these elements per line, possibly without adding other HTML elements?

Comment: @Šime, It's not a list and, quoting the text, `possibly without adding other HTML elements`.

Comment: 30 elements in a row that have the same class? In my book, that's a job for UL/LI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly the easiest way is:

```css
a {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

With this, you don't have to change the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `display: table-row` if you want equal width for all your link, flexible width being calculated to the max width of your links.

Or you can play with `:before` pseudo to create sort of a clear without floats and clear, in case it'd cause problems in your design.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/Sm8tK/

Comment: Worth noting that neither of those will work in IE7. Your `:before` example doesn't work in WebKit browsers. It can be fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Sm8tK/1/ (idea from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609279/css-to-line-break-before-after-a-particular-inline-block-item/4609491#4609491))