# Using inline-block display without the content floating left

Tags: html, css

I want the width of a div element to be equal to the width of the content inside it, and also (and more importantly) that any content after this div does not start to the right of the div(as though the div was `float:left;`), but display below the current div. 
I know one way is that after this div, I create another empty div and set `clear:both;`, but in my case that would not be very preferable.

Comment: Could you post your HTML and CSS code ?

Comment: can you specify why that is not preferable?

Comment: Just add a `<br>` after your current div?

Comment: @slacker, a whole website is already in operation and having to go through the whole code gain and inserting the empty div tags would be a last resort for me(or so i want to convince myself). If it was possible to just play around with the css, that would make my day!

Comment: @Jon, wow! it works...only that it also means I have to go through all my code and insert the `<br/>` tags! Any CSS solution?

Comment: @G Thuo, I think you should post some html and css as pith suggested

Comment: Here's my code:
`<div id="info">This is my bible!</div>
And I say It again!!!`
And here's the CSS:
`#info
{
 display:inline-block;
background-color:#CFFF9F;
 color:black;
 font-weight:normal;
 border:black solid 1px;
}`

Comment: You may should edit your question...

Comment: @pith, Any misunderstanding in my question?

Comment: @GThuo: "CSS solution" always goes together with "what browsers are you required to support?"

Comment: @Jon, mainly Mozilla, Chrome, Opera and IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the following may be close to what you need:

The HTML demo code is:

```
<div>
Some text may be before the element.
<div id="info">This is my bible!</div>And some text may follow. the element.
</div>
```

And the CSS styles are:

```
#info {
    display:inline;
    background-color:#CFFF9F;
    color:black;
    font-weight:normal;
    border:black solid 1px;
}
#info:after {
    content:"\A"; 
    white-space: pre; 
}
```

Fiddle reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/6FNQc/

**Explanation of How This Works**

Use `:after` to generate some content (known as a pseudo-element in CSS).  The "\A" is interpreted as a line break (linefeed) provided that the white space is preserved, hence you need to set `white-space: pre`.  Finally, the element has to be inline, hence `display: inline`.

Related References:
[CSS to line break before/after a particular `inline-block` item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609279/css-to-line-break-before-after-a-particular-inline-block-item)

To learn more about "\A" (linefeed), see:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings