# How to clear all elements after an element using a style and keeping inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` that I would like to keep `inline-block` but I want to keep any other elements from appearing on the same line as it.

- I know that `display:block` will clear all the elements after it.
- I know that adding a `BR` tag will clear all the elements after it.

But I would rather use a style such as `clear:both` except that only works for floating elements.

Is there a CSS style that I can use to clear all the elements after it while continuing to use `inline-block`?

I've seen another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609279/css-to-line-break-before-after-a-particular-inline-block-item) but no one actually answered the question. I'm 100% not interested in alternatives such as using floats. There was one answer using CSS using content after but it  does not work ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/dWkdp/1865/)).

```
#Container:after {
    content:"\a ";
    white-space:pre;
}
```

Here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dWkdp/1865/) to an example on JSFiddle. I want to add a break after BorderContainer20016.

*Let me repeat. I'm 100% not interested in alternatives such as using floats.*

Comment: The point of `inline`(and `inline-block`) is to keep elements on 1 line. It might help to add why you need `inline-block` to help others answer your question

Comment: I use inline-block to keep things on one line but also for setting explicit width. I use block to clear the line (stack items on top of each other) but it does not center horizontally. So I need something to stack vertically but also center. Check the example in the description. Using a BR after inline-block will work but it will cause other problems which is why I'm looking for a CSS solution.