# Is there any simpler way to make the few first letters in a list bold in HTML?

Tags: html

**1953** - crosses a short, sturdy dwarf breed of wheat with a high-yeidling American breed, creating a strain that responds well to fertalizer. It goes on to provide 95% of Mexico's wheat.

**1962** - Visits Delhi and brings his high-yielding strains of wheat to the Indian subcontinent in time to help mitigate mass starvation due to a rapidly expanding population

**1970** - receives the Nobel Peace Prize

**1983** - helps seven African countries dramatically increase their maize and sorghum yields

**1984** - becomes a distinguished professor at Texas A&M University

Like the above example, I would like to make an unordered list, and each time I should make the year number bold. Is there any way that I can do this at one time instead of make them bold every time I type each line?

Comment: Well, *how are you doing it* at the moment? Show us some HTML/CSS, otherwise we can't possibly tell if there is a *simpler* way.

Comment: Linna, you should select an accepted answer (given that one of them solved your problem). This way, the question will be marked as solved.

Answer (score 2):

The key idea is to use CSS to style the element wrapping the year *once*, in one place, no matter how many of those list items you have. It still requires some extra markup for each and every year, of course. I'll show you two examples.

### Using `ol`

You could use a [`ol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) (*ordered* list, because it seems you have chronologically ordered data) with the years wrapped in `span`s, like this:

```css
.chrono {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.chrono .year {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.chrono .year::after {
  content: " -";
}
```

```html
<ol class="chrono">
  <li><span class="year">1953</span> crosses a short, sturdy dwarf breed of wheat with a high-yeidling American breed, creating a strain that responds well to fertalizer. It goes on to provide 95% of Mexico's wheat.
  </li>
  <li><span class="year">1962</span> Visits Delhi and brings his high-yielding strains of wheat to the Indian subcontinent in time to help mitigate mass starvation due to a rapidly expanding population
  </li>
  <li><span class="year">1970</span> receives the Nobel Peace Prize
  </li>
  <li><span class="year">1983</span> helps seven African countries dramatically increase their maize and sorghum yields
  </li>
  <li><span class="year">1984</span> becomes a distinguished professor at Texas A&M University
</ol>
```

Hint: you can reduce the markup by removing the `class="year"` on each span element. You would then address them as `.chrono li span` via CSS.

### Using `dl`

Alternatively, you could use a [`dl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) (description list, as you describe details regarding a given year), maybe like so:

```css
.chrono {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.chrono dt {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
}

.chrono dd {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}

.chrono dd::after {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}

.chrono dt::after {
  content: " -";
}
```

```html
<dl class="chrono">
  <dt>1953</dt>
  <dd>crosses a short, sturdy dwarf breed of wheat with a high-yeidling American breed, creating a strain that responds well to fertalizer. It goes on to provide 95% of Mexico's wheat.</dd>
  <dt>1962</dt>
  <dd>Visits Delhi and brings his high-yielding strains of wheat to the Indian subcontinent in time to help mitigate mass starvation due to a rapidly expanding population</dd>
  <dt>1970</dt>
  <dd>receives the Nobel Peace Prize</dd>
  <dt>1983</dt>
  <dd>helps seven African countries dramatically increase their maize and sorghum yields</dd>
  <dt>1984</dt>
  <dd>becomes a distinguished professor at Texas A&M University</dd>
</dl>
```

Note: here, I'm using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4609491/3316645) to force the desired inline-appearance of the `dt` and `dd` elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in CSS. It will be done using JavaScript (e.g. explode function). The simplest is to tag a word in HTML markup...