# Style List Items Into Two Columns Centered

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-lists

I'm trying to style song lyrics that are stored in an unordered list.  Each lyric line is contained in a separate list item. I need these lyrics to be displayed in a two-column format **and** centered.  The code below is the closest that I've gotten but I still have not found a viable solution for centering the text.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```css
h3 {
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.phrases.floated {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #ccc; /* For demo purposes */
    
    width: 600px;
}

.phrases.floated li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}

.phrases.floated li:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    background-color: beige; /* For demo purposes */
    clear: both;
    margin-right: 20px;
}


/* Flexbox  */
.phrases.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    background-color: #ccc; /* For demo purposes */
    
    width: 600px;
    
}

.phrases.flexbox li {
    list-style-type: none;
    flex-basis: calc( 50% - 10px);
    text-align: left;
}

.phrases.flexbox li:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    background-color: beige; /* For demo purposes */
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <h3>Phrases Floated</h3>
    <ul class="phrases floated">
      <li>O beautiful for spacious skies</li>
      <li>For amber waves of grain</li>
      <li>For purple mountain majesties</li>
      <li>Above the fruited plain!</li>
      <li>America! America</li>
      <li>God shed His grace on thee</li>
      <li>And crown thy good with brotherhood</li>
      <li>From sea to shining sea!</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Phrases Flexbox</h3>
    <ul class="phrases flexbox">
      <li>O beautiful for spacious skies</li>
      <li>For amber waves of grain</li>
      <li>For purple mountain majesties</li>
      <li>Above the fruited plain!</li>
      <li>America! America</li>
      <li>God shed His grace on thee</li>
      <li>And crown thy good with brotherhood</li>
      <li>From sea to shining sea!</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: To be clear, you're saying that you want the entire row (like "O beautiful for spacious skies
For amber waves of grain") to be centered together? If so, why don't you just put them in the same `<li>` tag?

Comment: like that? - https://i.ibb.co/ncZsfWR/image.png

Comment: `text-align:center` would work for aligning the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
h3 {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.phrases {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #ccc; /* For demo purposes */
    width: 650px;
    padding: 0;
}

.phrases li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

.phrases li:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    background-color: beige; /* For demo purposes */
}

.phrases li:nth-of-type(2n):after {
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre; 
}
```

```html
<h3>Phrases</h3>
<ul class="phrases">
  <li>O beautiful for spacious skies</li>
  <li>For amber waves of grain</li>
  <li>For purple mountain majesties</li>
  <li>Above the fruited plain!</li>
  <li>America! America</li>
  <li>God shed His grace on thee</li>
  <li>And crown thy good with brotherhood</li>
  <li>From sea to shining sea!</li>
</ul>
```

I think this might be what you want. Basically, you can use `display: inline` instead of `float` and use a particular trick from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4609491/5732397 to force line breaks where you want them. Credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4767993/5732397 for the `display` idea, though `inline-block` didn't end up working as well as `inline`.

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with bootstrap.  But this will also work.

```css
.phrases {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.col-lg {
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid black;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <ul class="phrases">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg">
            <li>O beautiful for spacious skies</li>
          </div>
              <div class="col-lg">
            <li>For amber waves of grain</li>
          </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you need but I believe you need something like this.

I have used grid instead of flexbox. This can be done using flexbox also and I believe CSS stylesheet is made too much complicated unnecessarily.

```
/* Grid  */
.phrases.flexbox {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  background-color: #ccc; /* For demo purposes */
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.phrases.flexbox li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
}

.phrases.flexbox li:nth-of-type(2n + 1) {
  background-color: beige; /* For demo purposes */
}
```

[image]